# Use more than 2 images with crossfade.js

Tags: jquery, html, animation, cross-fade

I need to accomplish this effect http://mikefowler.me/crossfade.js/ with an array of 10 images. Crossfade.js requires a `start: image.png` and an `end: image2.png`. How can I do this with more than 2 images?

Comment: I don't think this is right plugin for what you need. Do you need some kind of animation on scroll or you really want 10 fading steps of same image?

Comment: I would like to somewhat recreate this effect www.propellr.com except with a more direct pair between the fades and the scroll.